# Prevent el-menu-item from adding "is-active" class when clicked

Tags: vuejs2, element-ui

Using [element-ui](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/menu) framework, how do I prevent el-menu component's el-menu-item from adding "is-active" class when clicked?

I don't want to just override the css class but I want to completely remove it.

[image]

Comment: What is el-menu a part of? I.e. What component framework are you using?

Comment: I'm using element ui framework. I've updated my question btw.

Comment: can share a snippet of your code, just to see what attributes you are passing and which nav mode you are using